# What is this NullPointerException supposed to mean?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jmonkeyengine

This code is giving me a java.lang.NullPointerException and I don't know why.
Exact error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.bminus.ttp.controller.HUD.bind(HUD.java:35)
    at de.lessvoid.nifty.screen.Screen.startScreen(Screen.java:210)
    at de.lessvoid.nifty.Nifty.gotoScreenInternal(Nifty.java:678)
    at de.lessvoid.nifty.Nifty.access$400(Nifty.java:77)
    at de.lessvoid.nifty.Nifty$1.perform(Nifty.java:635)
    at de.lessvoid.nifty.elements.EndOfFrameElementAction.perform(EndOfFrameElementAction.java:22)
    at de.lessvoid.nifty.Nifty.executeEndOfFrameElementActions(Nifty.java:439)
    at de.lessvoid.nifty.Nifty.handleDynamicElements(Nifty.java:358)
    at de.lessvoid.nifty.Nifty.update(Nifty.java:293)
    at com.jme3.niftygui.InputSystemJme.endInput(InputSystemJme.java:113)
    at com.jme3.input.InputManager.processQueue(InputManager.java:819)
    at com.jme3.input.InputManager.update(InputManager.java:883)
    at com.jme3.app.Application.update(Application.java:604)
    at com.bminus.ttp.ui.App.update(App.java:473)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.runLoop(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:151)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglDisplay.runLoop(LwjglDisplay.java:185)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.run(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:228)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

And here is the code it is pointing to:

```
public void bind(Nifty theNifty, Screen theScreen)
  {
    this.nifty = theNifty;
    this.screen = theScreen;
    this.screen.addKeyboardInputHandler(new DefaultInputMapping(), this);
    final ConsoleControl control = (ConsoleControl)this.nifty.createPopup("console-popup").findControl("console", ConsoleControl.class);
    control.output("The Third Power");
    control.output("Type 'help()' to get list of all available commands.");
    control.addCommandHandler(new ConsoleCommandHandler()
    {
       public void execute(String theString)
      {
        try
        {
          Object result = HUD.SHELL.evaluate(String.format("TTP.%s", new Object[] { theString }));
          if (result != null) {
            if ((result instanceof Collection)) {
              for (Object resultItems : (Collection)result) {
                control.output(resultItems.toString());
              }
            } else {
              control.output(result.toString());
            }
          }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
          control.output(String.format("Unknown command: %s", new Object[] { theString }));
        }
      }
    });
    SHELL.setVariable("TTP", this.consoleAPI);
  }
```

More specifically, this line exactly:

```
control.output("The Third Power");
```

What I want to know is why it is giving me a java.lang.NullPointerException and how I can fix this error and also how to make sure it never comes back. If anyone needs more information about what I want then just ask. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried debug mode in Eclipse? If not, you may want to download the Eclipse integrated development environment .. it will allow you quite a bit of troubleshooting (and writing ) aid!

Comment: it means you're trying to do something with an object that isn't there. Maybe it was never instantiated.

Comment: I am using jMonkey Engine (NetBeans) and I have to stick with it. @Erstwhilelll

Comment: @leigero How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code findControl method is returing null which is causing this nullpointer exception as it makes control null. Just wild wild wild guess and please ignore this if its not correct. Are you expecting to pass "console" in findControl method or it should be same as "console-popup". Sometimes we do type error and look into different direction.

Anyway Just to complete the answer you can add this line just after calling find Control method.

```
final ConsoleControl control = (ConsoleControl)this.nifty.createPopup("console-popup").findControl("console", ConsoleControl.class);
if(control == null){
//log error message if want
return;
}
```

Comment: I'll do this for now while I got through the ConsoleConntrol.class in the nifty project. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The variable `control` is `null`, and you attempt to call method `output()` on it.  You'll probably want to check it for `null` in an `if` statement before attempting to call methods on it.  If you're not expecting it to ever be `null`, try looking at why the previous line is returning `null`.

```
final ConsoleControl control = (ConsoleControl)this.nifty.createPopup("console-popup").findControl("console", ConsoleControl.class);
```

Comment: This may be a bit nooby but why would it return null and how would I check to see if it does?

Comment: The error stack says `at  com.bminus.ttp.controller.HUD.bind(HUD.java:35)`. Check if it is the same line.

Comment: It is the the line below the one he is specifying. @Ravinder

Comment: Yes. Line `34` is causing a `null` output for `control` variable. And hence is the NPE at `35`.

Comment: I don't really know this API you're using. I'm taking you at your word that HUD.java line 35 is the `control.output(...)` line you mention in your post.  This means that the `findControl()` method you call is returning `null`.  I'd consult the API documentation for that method, but I'd suspect it cannot find any control named "console" of type `ConsoleControl.class`

Comment: @Ravinder how do I make sure it does **Not** return null anymore though?

Comment: @1Poseidon3: Make sure that the `findControl` won't return a `null`.

Comment: @1Poseidon3 one possibility, after looking at nifty-gui source, is definitely that there is no control named "console" in the popup that is created in the result of your `createPopup()` call.  https://github.com/void256/nifty-gui/blob/1.4/nifty-core/src/main/java/de/lessvoid/nifty/screen/Screen.java#L433

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if `final ConsoleControl control ...`
returns a null

You could add the statement  `if (control == null) {System.out.println("I found the problem, now I have to figure out why control is null);}`